# Error getting state_dict from a serialized model in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, attributeerror

Already trained my encoder-decoder model and saved using :

```
model_state = {
             'encoder': encoder,
             'encoder_optimizer': encoder_optimizer,
             'decoder': decoder,
             'decoder_optimizer': decoder_optimizer
             }
torch.save(model_state, "best_model.pth.tar")
```

This works fine when I use the model stand-alone, but it gives me errors when I try to use my model within another app. Thus, I'm trying to load the model and save the encoder and decoder as state_dicts instead. This works for my encoder, but when I try:

```
checkpoint = torch.load(path_to_model, map_location=torch.device("cpu"))
decoder = checkpoint['decoder']
decoder = decoder.to(device)
encoder = checkpoint['encoder']
encoder = encoder.to(device)
torch.save(encoder.state_dict(), 'encoder.dict')
torch.save(decoder.state_dict(), 'decoder.dict')
```

It fails on `torch.save(decoder.state_dict(), 'decoder.dict')` and I get the error :

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "caption.py", line 31, in load_maps
    torch.save(decoder.state_dict(), 'decoder.dict')
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 695, in state_dict
    module.state_dict(destination, prefix + name + '.', keep_vars=keep_vars)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 695, in state_dict
    module.state_dict(destination, prefix + name + '.', keep_vars=keep_vars)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 696, in state_dict
    for hook in self._state_dict_hooks.values():
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 585, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Softmax' object has no attribute '_state_dict_hooks'
```

Is there a way to bypass this error or recreate the `state_dict` without having to retrain my model? I don't get why if I saved the whole model that I can't get the `state_dict` out of it, which is presumably a part of the model.

This is the output from calling `for m in decoder.modules(): print(m)`:

```
DecoderWithAttention(
  (attention): Attention(
    (encoder_att): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (decoder_att): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (full_att): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1, bias=True)
    (relu): ReLU()
    (softmax): Softmax(dim=1)
  )
  (embedding): Embedding(9490, 512)
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (decode_step): LSTMCell(2560, 512, bias=1)
  (init_h): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (init_c): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (f_beta): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
  (sigmoid): Sigmoid()
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=9490, bias=True)
)
Attention(
  (encoder_att): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (decoder_att): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
  (full_att): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1, bias=True)
  (relu): ReLU()
  (softmax): Softmax(dim=1)
)
Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1, bias=True)
ReLU()
Softmax(dim=1)
Embedding(9490, 512)
Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
LSTMCell(2560, 512, bias=1)
Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
Sigmoid()
Linear(in_features=512, out_features=9490, bias=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving model like this.

```
torch.save({'state_dict': decoder.state_dict()}, 'decoder.pth.tar')
```

Comment: Sorry, typo on 'decoder.pth', I did save as .pth.tar and edited the question to reflect that. I didn't save the state_dict though, and will in the future, but need a way to get the state_dict without retraining.

Comment: I can't call `decoder.state_dict()` without it bombing on the error

Comment: @TylerLozano can you try to remove the softmax layer and saving? Did you create your own Softmax layer module?